# Tacky Dropdown Menu Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

[tacky dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVuDo.jpg)

Hi!

Sorry if I've not framed this question correctly but I'm new here. I have this wordpress website where I cannot seem to get rid of these tacky dropdowns. I need them slightly to the right like a proper dropdown and asking these on Facebook groups led me here as I was suggested to mess with the CSS to get this fixed. I know some basic functions but something like this is out of my league. I was hoping if someone well versed on CSS or wordpress styling could help me out here.

Also, if it helps I'm using newsmag theme.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i had checked your website. kindly go and edit the style.css file and search for `.sf-menu li ul `  on that remove left styling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to align to the left side of the buttons, the style is found on line 5668 of /wp-content/themes/Newsmag/style.css:

```
.sf-menu li ul {
  left: -9px;
  z-index: 99;
  /* responsive portrait tablet */
}
```

Remove or comment out the line "left: -9px;". Then your dropdowns will line up on the left side.

Please clarify if that's not what you want.